# How to separate zones into individual maps

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I am using ArcMap 10.3 with a Basic license.

I have a single map split into four zones.
[image]

I would like to split this single map into four individual maps / data frames focusing on a single zone.
[image]

Is this possible? I know that I can just zoom to an extent and print that, but I would like to completely separate the content of Zone A from anything else. 

In the above example, I wouldn't want to see the data on the edge of Zone D in my Zone A map.

I'd like to avoid duplicating and renaming my data four different times in order to just highlight and delete the excess data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [Data Driven Pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003n000000). You can use your areas as your layer, and using a [Definition Query](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Using_Page_Definition_Queries/00s90000003p000000/), can exclude all the other areas.

Comment: So, I could likely add a "Zone" field to my data, and just query which zone I want to display?

Comment: Add another layer of the same zones, and within that layer set the definition query. And then yes

Comment: @nomkins Another option, assuming your zones are polygons, is to look at the dataframe clipping option. You can set a clip on a dataframe so that only features within a given shape are shown. This can be set to affect layers individually and wouldn't require modifying your data. May more may not be able to be combined with DDP - can't recall if I've tested or done that.